# Iphone to read and display serial data stream wirelessly

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, serial-port, wifi

I have a device that provides a constant stream of output data through a serial port. I want to use this data and display it usefully in an app. I am open to both Bluetooth or WiFi connections. I'd rather use bluetooth but from what I have read so far bluetooth is a non-starter without the MFI program so my focus is mostly on a wifi connection. I haven't worked with any serial I/O in any apps before.

This product caught my eye as a simple solution for the transmission. Will this product serve the purpose I'm looking to use it for? Is there a better option that I have?

http://www.usconverters.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=404

I have very limited ios development experience and programming in general, I'm probably a little over my head here but anxious to move forward with the project. I appreciate any helpful information.